# How to insert value as null if column don't exist in JSON?

Tags: python, json

```
for inv in result['Invoices']:
     print(inv['InvoiceID'])

     for li in inv['LineItems']:

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [azureserver].dbo.[xero_invoiceliTest](InvoiceId,CurrencyRate,LineAmountTypes,LineItemId,Description,Quantity,LineAmount,TaxAmount,AccountCode) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",inv['InvoiceID'],inv['CurrencyRate'],inv['LineAmountTypes'],li['LineItemID'],li['Description'],li.['Quantity'],li['LineAmount'],li['TaxAmount'],li['AccountCode'])
            conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

I get KeyError: 'Quantity' because Quantity is not always present in the JSON file. How do I insert Quantity as Null when they are not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict.get(key, default)` as in

```
li.get('Quantity', None)
```